# Creating the Correct NSString for Image Uploading with xCode and Amazon S3

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-s3, nsstring

I'm having difficulties working out a way to the photo upload to give the correct filenames.
I want to make each image uploaded look like this.

@”0011/2013-11-01-10-15-01-062.png"

@”0012/2013-11-01-10-15-01-067.png"

@”0013/2013-11-01-10-15-01-069.png"

Whats happening here is 0011, 0012 etc are incrementing by 1 every-time a new picture is uploaded. And then the Date,Month,Day,Hour,Minute,Second are added at the end. I'm not sure how to go about and achieving this.

```
    S3PutObjectRequest *imageUpload = [[[S3PutObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" "]
                                                              inBucket:[Constants pictureBucket]] autorelease];
    imageUpload.contentType = @"image/png";
    imageUpload.data        = imageData;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out `NSDateComponents`, it’ll get the data you need for your `[NSString stringWithFormat:]`